Convergence of Laplacian operator in $H^2(\Omega) \, (\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2)$
I am studying the paper link and I have $||\Delta u_n -\Delta u||_{H^1(\Omega)} \to 0$ in page 71. But how to show that $||\Delta^2 u_n -\Delta^2 u||_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0$?
check the blue marked box

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

It seems that this is a typo, and it should read $\| \Delta u_n -\Delta u\|_{L^2(0,T;L^2)} \to0$.
However, th argument above (2.23) is already wrong:
The embedding $L^\infty(0,T;H^2)$ into $L^\infty(0,T;H^1)$ is not compact.
Hence, it is not clear that this claim about strong convergence is valid.
(Take $\phi \in H^2$, $\phi\ne0$, now define $u_n(t,x):= \sin(nt) \phi(x)$.)
